# Need to open the application when SMS arrives and spell the arrived SMS in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there is any possibility for an application to open immediately when an SMS arrives and spell this SMS?

If so, how to do this app i.e., how to open an application whenever SMS arrives?

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5946045/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 5):

No chance. Apple does not provide a documented API for SMS access and will reject such an app, even if you managed to implement it in the way you intend.

Comment: I want to add that *luckily* Apple doesn't allow that. It would not only be a *huge* privacy issue, it would also be extremely annoying.

Comment: @DarkDust:  I don't think luck has anything to do with it.  It's a deliberate design decision by Apple.

Comment: @JeremyP: I know it's a deliberate choice, mainly because of the privacy issues (did I state otherwise ?). But they could have decided otherwise (IIRC Nokia does allows this and other perversities; e.g. you can hook into the dialer and do nasty things), so we are lucky (as in: thank your favorite deity that Apple decided that way).

Comment: @DarkDust Pretty sure Android allows this too, but Android is always very clear about what permissions each application has, and there will be a big bold warning that application `x` that you are about to install will have access to your SMS's. Don't know about Nokia though, haven't used one in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this on iOS device due to platform restrictions.
You can only show SMS-sending dialog, but no more. That's actual for latest iOS 4.3.3.